# How do I convert relative dates to absolute dates?

Tags: python, datetime, netcdf

I am looking at a netcdf file through Python and the date on the netcdf file is 138276, which is the number of hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00. This date corresponds to October 7. How I can convert this date of 138276 hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00 into the format of 2015-10-07 00:00:00?

Comment: not sure how you got `2015-10-07 00:00:00` after adding those hours to that date/time?

Answer (score 7):

Since the start date is constant, create a datetime object and just add whatever hours you want [using datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0)

new = start + timedelta(hours=138276)

print(new)
2015-10-10 00:00:00
```

The answer is also `2105-10-10` not `2015-10-07`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the netCDF4 package, you should use the [`num2date`](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section7) function.

```
In [1]: from netCDF4 import num2date

In [2]: date = num2date(138276, 'hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00', calendar='standard')

In [3]: date
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 10, 12, 0)
```

most likely, your netCDF time variable also has the units and calendar in there so you probably don't need to hard code those.  In fact, the num2date function will take a list or array of dates.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`dt.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse your string into a datetime object and then construct a [`dt.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object and set param `hours=your_val` to add the required number of hours:

```
In [25]:
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + dt.timedelta(hours=138276)

Out[25]:
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 10, 12, 0)
```

It's unclear to me how you arrive at a target date of `2015-010-07` when it's `2015-10-10`?

Answer (score 3):

Have `timedelta` increment the hours properly. Your date calculation is a little off tho.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

old_date = '2000-01-01'

curr_date = datetime.strptime(old_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(hours=138276 )

print(curr_date)

2015-10-10 12:00:00
```

To change output format, change `curr_date` to:

```
print(curr_date.strftime('%Y%m%d%H'))

2015101012
```

Comment: How can I convert the date from format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYYMMDDHH?

Comment: Check my edit for that. You need to implement `strftime`